# randomize exported file name from ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, filenames, ms-access-2016

I have a function to randomize file name. I called it GetNextFileName.

```
Option Compare Database

Function GetNextFileName(ByVal strFile As String) As String
  Dim strResult As String
  Dim intCount As Integer
  
  strResult = Replace(strFile, "1", "*") 'add wildcard
  strResult = Dir(strResult)
  
  While strResult <> ""
    intCount = intCount + 1
    strResult = Dir()
  Wend
  
  GetNextFileName = Replace(strFile, "1", intCount + 1)
  
End Function
```

and I am exporting attachments from my Access table to folder in which I need to randomize file names to avoid duplication error from Access while saving the files.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExtractAllAttachments(ByVal TableName As String, ByVal AttachmentColumnNane As String)
Dim rsMainRecords As DAO.Recordset2
Dim rsAttachments As DAO.Recordset2

Set rsMainRecords = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT " & AttachmentColumnNane & _
                                            " FROM " & TableName & _
                                            " WHERE " & AttachmentColumnNane & ".FileName IS NOT NULL")
                                            
Do Until rsMainRecords.EOF   
  Set rsAttachments = rsMainRecords.Fields(AttachmentColumnNane).value       
  Do Until rsAttachments.EOF      
    Dim outputFileName As String        
    outputFileName = GetNextFileName.GetNextFileName(rsAttachments.Fields("FileName").value)
    outputFileName = "F:\SHARING\Tracking System\file" & "\" & outputFileName        
    rsAttachments.Fields("FileData").SaveToFile outputFileName      
    rsAttachments.MoveNext
  Loop
  rsAttachments.Close        
  rsMainRecords.MoveNext
Loop
    
rsMainRecords.Close
    
Set rsAttachments = Nothing
Set rsMainRecords = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

I tried this but the names of the files are not randomized or adding a prefix to it!
Any advice?

Comment: No need to randonise the filename just use a timestamp as follows -  Dim sFilename As String :  sFilename = "U:\Data\rpt" & Format(Now(), "yyyymmddHHMMSS") & ".txt"

Comment: Or use the FileSystemObject.GetTempName to let windows create a filename. (in case you'll produce more than 1 file per second)

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- Step through your function to see what is happening.